# Shell remove pattern from filename

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, command

I have a lot of files named like `activity_unpublish_39x39.png`, `abc_29x29.png` and etc.

I want to convert the name to `activity_unpublish.png` (remove `_39x39`)
and `abc.png` (remove `_29x29`).

Could anyone tell me how I can achieve that?

It would be better working on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following small shell script should work on Linux and also on Mac OS. Note that it's working in the current folder, further you have to change `pat` and `suf` to your needs (here `suf="\.png"` and `pat="_[0-9]+x[0-9]+$suf"` to work with your given example).
It uses `sed` with `-E` which is undocumented in the [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed). It's the option to go in Mac OS which is known as `-r` in Linux. In Linux it is also existent [but as said not documented](http://blog.dmitryleskov.com/small-hacks/mysterious-gnu-sed-option-e/):

```
#!/bin/sh
suf="\.png"
pat="_[0-9]+x[0-9]+$suf"

for f in *; do
   if [[ $f =~ $pat ]]; then
      newName=$(echo "$f" | sed -E "s/$pat/$suf/g")
      mv "$f" "$newName"
   fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks, since my question is solved and there is some urgent tasks I need to do, I will try your answer later. Thanks for your answer, I add a like on it :)

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer from my kind colleague.
Use this shell script.

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in *_[0-9]*x[0-9]*.png
do
  mv $file $(echo $file | sed 's/_[0-9]*x[0-9]*//')
done
```

Comment: You could mark this as answer as it solves your problem.

Comment: @AndreKampling thanks, when I click on it, it says you can accept your own answer tomorrow, thanks for your kind reminder.